# Frank hertz experiment

Tags: classical-mechanics

In our practical, we used argon gas instead of mercury. Is there is any advantage of using it over Mercury ?(other than it's already available in gaseous form)

Comment: One big advantage: argon vapor is reasonably nontoxic, unlike mercury vapor.

Comment: Argon is also inexpensive as it is collected in non-trivial quantities as a by-product of nitrogen liquification (and kept around because they can sell it to wleders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In school, we use both version of Franck-Hertz:

- mercury
- neon (I hope, that it is not too different from argon)

The advantage of mercury is that one can excite the mercury atoms at relatively low voltage, i.e. 4.9 V, and the second excitation at 2x4.9V, and so on. The big disadvantage is however, that the mercury tube has to be heated inside an oven.

The neon and hopefully the argon version, works without heating, which makes the handling much easier. On the other hand, neon and presumably argon as well, needs higher voltage to excite transitions of the outer electrons. For neon, it is 16 V and multiples of it. Another big advantage, of the neon-configuration: You can see light zones from relaxing atoms inside the tube, since it is not hidden inside the oven.